# LibGDX Table height changes after adding an Actor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am using the following code to create a Table with a ScrollPane. It renders correctly when it is empty, but as soon as I add items to the table, its height reduces by about half.

```
// Init Stage & container table
stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(Consts.SCREEN_WIDTH, Consts.SCREEN_HEIGHT));
Table container = new Table();
stage.addActor(container);
container.setFillParent(true);

// Init the scrollable table
final Table yourTurnMatches = new Table();
yourTurnMatches.background(Assets.getSolidColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));
final ScrollPane yourTurnMatchesScroll = new ScrollPane(yourTurnMatches);
yourTurnMatchesScroll.setScrollingDisabled(true, false);
yourTurnMatches.defaults().expand().space(4).top();

// Add the inner content to the container table
container.row().top().expandX().uniform();
Table matchTitles = new Table();
matchTitles.row().expandX().uniform().padTop(10).padBottom(10);
matchTitles.setBackground(Assets.getSolidColorDrawable(Color.DARK_GRAY));
matchTitles.add(txtYourTurn);
matchTitles.add(txtTheirTurn);
matchTitles.add(txtFinished);
container.add(matchTitles).colspan(3).fillX();
container.row().top().expand().uniform().spaceLeft(5).spaceRight(5);
container.add(yourTurnMatchesScroll).fill();
yourTurnMatches.row();

// Add button (this causes the Table height to go to about half of the original height)
Button btn = new Button(greenButtonStyle);
yourTurnMatches.add(btn).width(target.getWidth()*0.8f);
```

I am using LibGDX version 1.9.2.

Any ideas what might cause the Table height to change?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Seems like the problem was caused by the Table header row:

```
container.row().top().expandX().uniform();
Table matchTitles = new Table();
matchTitles.row().expandX().uniform().padTop(10).padBottom(10);
matchTitles.setBackground(Assets.getSolidColorDrawable(Color.DARK_GRAY));
matchTitles.add(txtYourTurn);
matchTitles.add(txtTheirTurn);
matchTitles.add(txtFinished);
container.add(matchTitles).colspan(3).fillX();
```

The header row actually took the half of the space reserved for the Table, but only when the latter row contained at least one actor. The fillX() for the header didn't make the header stretch and fill the whole height but it still reserved the space.

This seems to be really weird behaviour to me and I would still like to hear a proper reason for this happening.

My solution was to redesign the whole screen and leave out the header row because it is no more required.